# Find element with certain text using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, django, selenium, testcase

Currently, I am using this and it works.

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a/h4[text()="item I want"]').click()
```

Is there a better way to select by text? I feel like code readability suffers immensely using xpath.

Simple HTML example that can be any number of elements. The purpose is to test a specific wine that is added to the database for a functional test.

```
{% extends 'wine/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <section id="wine_content">
        <div class="cards">

            {% for wine in wines %}
            <div class="card">
                <a href="/wine/{{ wine.id }}">
                    <h4>{{ wine.name }}</h4>
                    <p>{{ wine.vintage }}</p>
                    <p>{{ wine.description}}</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </section>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you post the full html for the element in question?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to improve the code readability, you should see to follow a page object pattern.

A first step would be to define the locator in a variable with an explicit name:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

```py
item_wine_pinot_noir = (By.XPATH, "//a/h4[text()='%s']" % "Pinneau noir")
browser.find_element(*item_wine_pinot_noir).click()
```

Comment: What is By? Is this a Java only class? I cannot find info on it for Python.

Comment: @Michael Bruce, it's an import from `selenium.webdriver.common.by`

Comment: Thank you! This is a really great help! I will hold out on marking solved to see if there are other ways. So far this is wonderful.

Comment: browser.get_element(By.XPATH, "//a/h4[text()='%s']" % 'wine name') works... but I cannot get your example with the tuple - item_wine_pinot_noir to be accepted in find_element(tuple).

Comment: Django and using Django templates.

Comment: @Michael Bruce, the `get_element` doesn't exists in the official API (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Anyway, if I forgot the asterisk in front of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('item I want').click()
```

Comment: You would think this would work, but I am not having luck with it. Could it be that there is an h4 in link? I even removed the h4 just in case and it still failed the FT.

Comment: Actually this should work even with `<h1>`, `<p>`, `<span>` inside a link... but seems that `find_element_by_link_text()` not always works as expected